# ; at end of condition causing unexpected behaviour

Tags: java

Just found a bug in this code :

```
    for(String link : tempList1){
        if(!tempList2.contains(link));{
            listToPopulate.add(link);
        }
    }
```

The ';' at the end of if(!tempList2.contains(link)) causes the condition to evaluate to true, even though it should be false. Why is this occurring ?

Fix is to just remove the ';'

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The compiler sees an `if` condition followed by a stand-alone block.  With standard indenting, it would look like this:

```
for(String link : tempList1){
    if(!tempList2.contains(link))
        ;  // ; is a no-op statement.
    {
        listToPopulate.add(link);
    }
}
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NOP#NOP_code

> The simplest possible statement in C that behaves like a NOP is the so called null statement, which is just a semi-colon in a context requiring a statement.

Java inherited this syntax from C.

Answer (score 5):

The `;` in line 2 ends the block following the `if`. The next `{` opens a new block that has no condition around it.

Answer (score 3):

```
if(expr);

{
  dosomething();
}
```

is the same as

```
if(expr)
{
}

{
  dosomething();
}
```

e.g. the block containing dosomething is not part of the if statement since the ; terminates the if statement.

The if statement is not evaluating to true, it's just not relevant.

Answer (score 1):

As others said,

```
if([condition]);
  somecode;
```

is similar to

```
if([condition]) 
  {}
somecode
```

If you are using Eclipse, you can enable the "empty statement" warning. This will let you see easily when such an empty statement is written, as this is generally unintended and can be annoying to debug. It is in Eclipse preferences (Java > Compiler > Errors/Warnings).

Answer (score 0):

Because the `;` is causing the end of the `if` condition, causing the `if` statement itself to have no effect.

The above is equivalent to:

```
for(String link : tempList1){
    if(!tempList2.contains(link)) {
         // do nothing
    }

    // the below is just an empty block, it will be executed always.

    {
        listToPopulate.add(link);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The evaluation of the condition does not change. What does change, however, is that the following line is no longer **inside** the loop and is executed unconditionally:

```
listToPopulate.add(link);
```

In other words, the code becomes equivalent to:

```
for(String link : tempList1){
    if(!tempList2.contains(link)) {
    }
    listToPopulate.add(link);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Semicolon designates the end of the statement and {} indicate a new block of code. So the condition is evaluated and ignored as there is  a semicolon. and `listToPopulate.add(link);` is always executed as it is not tied to earlier if statement.